# WebApps Second Anniversary Contest

Tags: discussion, contest

Congratulations on making it ***two years*** as a graduated site! Such an occasion should be honored -- so we're running a little anniversary event here to celebrate your second birthday.

### How do I participate?

Between **5 November 2012** and **2 December 2012** do one of the following:

- Answer an old question well enough to receive the Revival or Necromancer badge
- Vote to close a question (or flag close vote) that was asked before 2012

For the badges, one will get credit if the answer is ***both*** posted and gets a badge during the contest (not necessarily in the same week; one will be in the drawing for the week they get the badge).

For close votes, credit is given if the question actually closes at some point during the week. Questions that are reopened will not count towards one’s point totals. Mods will go through the close vote list at the end of each week to help close questions that should be closed but couldn't get enough votes.

The breakdown is as follows:

- 4 points for each Revival badge
- 5 points for each Necromancer badge (note that you'll possibly already have Revival as well)
- 1 point for each closed question

Each point is one chance to win for that week (so if one gets the Revival badge you've got 4 chances to win out of however many points everyone on the site got for that week)

### What can I win?

Each week, two winners randomly each week, who will each get:

- **EITHER**: A Webapps t-shirt or a Stack Exchange mug
- A Stack Exchange Sharpie

At the end of the contest, we'll pool the points of everyone who hasn't won yet and draw **two more winners** who will receive a special, limited edition Webapps logo plushie.

### Contest Rules and Fine Print

- All activities must occur within the time period of the contest. We shall give prior notice to the Dev Team at Stack Exchange to handle logging this information.
- You must have a registered Web Applications account in good standing, with a valid email address, to be eligible.
- Contest open to every man, woman, and child (over 13, as per our TOS) on planet Earth, except those men, women, or children living in places where contests like this are somehow illegal — or the relevant contest laws in your jurisdiction are so obnoxious that awarding the prize becomes impractical.
- You cannot win more than one prize. The runner up will receive the unclaimed prize.
- **Moderators are exempt from earning points for closed questions**. Only non-diamond users can earn points for closures.
- If you live in an area of the world where it is logistically impossible for us to get your prize to you — like, say, because your nearest computer hardware store is 3000 nautical miles away — we’ll do our best to work with you and make it happen.
- We will try to be as fair as possible, but all of our judgments are final and binding.

That's it! Have at it, everyone!

Comment: yay ! Another contest !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final Top Prize Winners!

[image: jacob]

[image: alexlmuller]

Answer (score 7):

### Week One Winners!

[image: john c]

[image: jmax]

**EDIT:** Because Ben hasn't registered his account, he is disqualified from winning. The Week One winner has been reassigned. Congrats to **JMax** for winning Week One!

Comment: Huzzah! Although sad now I can't win a Webapps plushie :-p

Answer (score 7):

### Week Two Winners!

[image: manish]

[image: user]

Comment: Yay! Swag! :) Should I be worried if I haven't been emailed yet? Or are the emails sent out after Dec 2nd?

Comment: @Manishearth Emails will be sent out en masse, once the contest is over. It saves me some trouble! :D

Comment: Makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

### Week Three Winners!

[image: Furhmanator]

[image: Al Everett]

Answer (score 3):

### Week Four Winners!

[image: jorg]

[image: niko]

Comment: Eight Days of Malaise gracefully bowed out. Congratulations to **Niko Nyman**!